# How can I test two strings I received with frombody in postman?

Tags: c#, postman, http-post

I have an httppost method, this method performs the forgot password process and for this, it takes the user's mail and the newly entered password, I received them as FromBody, but while testing the postman I am getting the following error. How can I test these?

---

```
[HttpPost("forgetuserpassword")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> forgetUserPassword([FromBody]string user_mail,string new_password)
    {
        return Ok( await _userService.ForgetPassword(user_mail, new_password));
       
        
    }
```

I have another httppost method that I get with frombody but I only get one value in it and it works when I test postmande like this. However, when I do the same for the post method where I get these two strings, it gives an error.

This is how I can test the post method in the postman, where I get a single string value with frombody.

[image]

this is how i tried the code i shared above in postman.logically it should be like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second post body is not valid JSON, try:

```
[
  "string1",
  "string2"
]
```

If you want to allow for multiple strings to be accepted, update your Method signature to this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> forgetUserPassword([FromBody]List<string> strings)
```

But, I would recommend using an Object in this case, like so:

```
public ForgotPasswordObject 
{ 
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string NewPassword {get;set;}
}
```

Then your method could look like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> forgetUserPassword([FromBody]ForgotPasswordObject forgotPassword)
{
    return Ok( await _userService.ForgetPassword(forgotPassword.Email, forgotPassword.NewPassword));
}
```

And finally, your JSON would be structured like:

```
{
  "email": "myemail@whatever.com",
  "newPassword":"1234"
}
```

Comment: when i do this I get this error.                                                                                              
{
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '', line 1, position 1."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-02907af6c697464b88cda4f7d28d6b50-51f029e7b3c35a46-00"
}

Comment: Are you sue that endpoint accepts an array of strings?

Comment: I am sending two strings. I don't know if I'm sending a string array.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on the endpoint you are hitting?

Comment: what kind of document I shared the code above.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the beginning, you'll want to accept a list for that method. 
Let me update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use correct JSON Format to use more than one field.

[image: IMG JSON Object]

```json
{
    "Email": "michael@gmail.com",
    "NewPassword": "1234567890"
}
```

Or

[image: IMG JSON Array]

```json
[
    "michael@gmail.com",
    "1234567890"
]
```

If it's a JSON Object use {} or [] if it's JSON Array